# Parâmetro recebendo parâmetros

Tags: javascript

Estou com dificuldade em entender esse código, sou bem iniciante.. na linha indicada o parâmetro da função anônima de cima está recebendo outros parâmetros? parâmetros podem receber parâmetros? Não consigo entender como esse código está funcionando

```
function calculator (num1, num2) {
    return function (callback) {
      return callback(num1, num2); // ESSA LINHA <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    };
  }

var sum = calculator(10, 2);

console.log( 'O resultado da soma é:' );
  console.log(sum(function (number1, number2) {
    return number1 + number2;
  }));
```

Comment: Eles podem ser invocados porque são funções. Sim, você pode passar uma função como argumento para uma função! :) Isso se chama _callback_. Eu marquei a sua pergunta como duplicada pois já foi respondida aqui no site. O aviso acima da pergunta tem um link para a pergunta sobre o assunto.